# Gnuplot error while CalcHEP process

Tags: gnuplot

I dont know if this is the wright place to ask but school's server gave the error below while doing a process in Calchep batch mode. Its obviously about gnuplot but I have no idea since I didnt touched program's code.

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000`
                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000`
                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`
`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000
                                ^`
"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000
                                                        ^`
"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000`
                                                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000`
                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000`
                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000`
                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000`
                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`
`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000`
                                ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option`

`set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000`
                                        ^
`"gnuplot_instructions", line 1: warning: deprecated color option$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple color option for the `png` terminal of gnuplot is gone, see https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1155/ ; the color specification format has changed too.

You need to change that script; if I understand the change you need is from

```
set term png transparent medium xffffff x000000 x000000 xadd8e6 xadd8e6 x000000
```

to

```
set terminal png transparent medium background "#ffffff" 
set linetype 0 lc rgb "#000000"
set linetype 1 lc rgb "#000000"
set linetype 2 lc rgb "#add8e6"
set linetype 3 lc rgb "#add8e6"
set linetype 4 lc rgb "#000000"
```

...and so on.